# How to do looping in jQuery?

Tags: php, jquery, yii2

I have some code for dynamic form on yii2, but I use dynamic form for add more form, and I want to add with jQuery but dynamic form change id if I add more form, and jQuery is not working on another form.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#transactiondetails-0-jumlah, #transactiondetails-0-harga').keyup(function() {
            var jumlah  = $('#transactiondetails-0-jumlah').val();
            var harga = $('#transactiondetails-0-harga').val();
            var total = jumlah * harga;
            $('#transactiondetails-0-total').val(total);
        });
    });
</script>
```

I want change > "transactiondetails-0-jumlah" to transactiondetails-1-jumlah and more, and how to do looping on jQuery to change the id number

Comment: Use the same class on the new content and bind a single delegated event handler to it. See the duplicate for more information

Comment: tanks, problem has solved